# What is the iOS equivalent to FirebaseInstanceId?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In android when I want to get stable identifier that uniquely identifies the app instance I can call FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId(). What is the iOS equivalent to this method in Firebase scope?

Comment: Have you gone through `Firebase` documentation? Well, what feature of `Firebase` are you trying to use?

Comment: Implementing FCM. I have gone through the documentation but haven't find it. However I am sure it should be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about `Firebase` but after a brief peak into the docs I see it should be `FIRInstanceID.instanceID().getIDWithHandler( {string, error in})`

Answer (score 0):

In iOS Objective C we can use like this Firebase 6.27.0

```
[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] getIDWithHandler:^(NSString *identity, NSError *error) {
     if (error != nil) {
       NSLog(@"Error fetching remote instance ID: %@", error);
     } else {
       NSLog(@"Remote instance ID: %@", identity);
     }
     NSLog(@"IID22 %@", identity);
   }];
```

and for Token we can use this

```
[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] instanceIDWithHandler:^(FIRInstanceIDResult * _Nullable result,
                                                        NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error fetching remote instance ID: %@", error);
        } else {
            token = result.token;
        }
        NSLog(@"Token %@", result.token);
       
    }];
```